# PowerMock + EasyMock: private void method without invokation

Tags: java, junit4, easymock, powermock

Good time!

I need to substitute the class' private void method with a mock implementation, and can't to figure out how to do this. I've tried to use such a construction:

```
Test test = PowerMock.createPartialMock(Test.class, "setId");
PowerMock.expectPrivate(test , "setId", EasyMock.anyLong()).andAnswer(
    new IAnswer<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void answer() throws Throwable {
            return null;
        }
    });
PowerMock.replay(test);
```

but the internal PowerMock's class called WhiteBox invokes my "setId" method which is wrong for my task. Could someone, please, suggest, how to avoid the method invokation and possibly to replace the method body with a custom one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally. I've got the solution.
The problem was I missed the following annotations:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Test.class)
```

Anyway, it seems rather confusing that to make the PowerMock working I need to add some annotations. If that wasn't a legacy code I'd prefer Mockito.

Comment: Those annotations are necessary in order to get PowerMock to load classes through its custom ClassLoader. That's where the byte code manipulation and reflection happen to allow you to mock legacy code that Mockito won't handle.

In general, if you can start a project off using Mockito, you (hopefully) won't get to a point where you need PowerMock.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure that I get the question. 
But for me code below works perfect and just string `"Invoked!"` is getting printed
and if I remove `test.setS(33L);` test will fail with exception:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(MainTest.Test2.class)
public class MainTest {

    @Test
    public void testName() throws Exception {
        Test2 test = PowerMock.createPartialMock(Test2.class, "setS");
        PowerMock.expectPrivate(test , "setS", EasyMock.anyLong()).andAnswer(
                new IAnswer<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public Void answer() throws Throwable {
                        System.out.println("Invoked!");
                        return null;
                    }
                }).atLeastOnce();
        PowerMock.replay(test);
        test.setS(33L);
        PowerMock.verify(test);

    }


    class Test2 {
        long s;

        private long getS() {
            return s;
        }

        private void setS(long s) {
            this.s = s;
            System.out.println("Not this!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. If I do exactly the same thing the original setS() method is invoked and so that the original method contains a logic that can't be processed in a unit test, an exception is thrown.

Comment: According to the PowerMock's internal code, there is a WhiteBox class that invokes (WhiteboxImpl.performMethodInvocation(instance, methodToExpect, arguments);) the original method when you call the PowerMock.expectPrivate() method... I need to avoid the original method invokation...